# Firefox private window flaky localStorage?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firefox, local-storage

Some background - I'm currently working on a React/Typescript web-based project where we are relying on local storage to set up some fields that are later used by our authentication logic. These items should be set very early during the app start up via `localStorage.setItem('item', value)` and later accessed via `localStorage.getItem('item')`

We have observed a very strange issue specific to FireFox private mode where the items are never added to localStorage at the beginning of the app life cycle thus breaking some of our authentication logic. In addition, when we try to reproduce the breaking scenario but also observe localStorage via the storage tab in the Firefox debugger while going through the repro steps, the issue doesn't occur.

Is anyone aware of any issues with firefox localstorage that could cause this?

We have a workaround using cookies but would prefer not to have to add this fallback for every use of localStorage. In addition, this issue doesn't occur on Chrome or Edge

Firefox version - 75.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Does the auth flow open a new tab or window? Does the issue occur with  `sessionStorage`?

Comment: yes it opens a new tab but that shouldn't affect localStorage even in private mode correct? Also, yeah we observed this same issue with sessionStorage

Comment: I wonder if it's still [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1453699) lingering on - other comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61875175

Comment: interesting find, they suggest using the pref `dom.storage.next_gen` in FF - let me give that a try and see

Comment: It works with `dom.storage.next_gen` enabled! So looks like that setting is not standard yet on firefox so we'll have to continue with a workaround. Thanks for your help!